# What is the indication of Result as Cache in httpfox

Tags: jmeter

I am getting Result as Cache for particular request in Httpfox and type as application/json

Answer (score 0):

Real browsers download embedded resources like images, scripts, styles, asynchronous requests results, but do it **only once**. During subsequent requests aforementioned entities are being returned from the browser cache.

JMeter provides [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) in order to simulate above behavior.

I think that you might also like to add the following test elements to your test plan to make your JMeter test even more realistic:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to send browser headers like [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
- Configure [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to download embedded resources using thread pool as per [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide